# Target not set error upon starting storyboard

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I'm trying to convert a XAML based storyboard to a code behind one, so that I can use multiple instances of the storyboard on many objects simultaneously. I write this factory method to create the animation for me, but I seem to get Target not set, when I start the storyboard. can someone help me out, I also intend to teach myself an effective way of writing code-behind storyboards.

```
public static Storyboard CreateSimpleTranslation(double x, double y, TimeSpan timespan, FrameworkElement target)
    {
        // original storyboard
        //<Storyboard x:Name="MoveUp">
        //    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateY)" 
        //        Storyboard.TargetName="itemsControl">
        //        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
        //        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.02" Value="-122">
        //            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
        //                <CircleEase EasingMode="EaseIn"/>
        //            </EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
        //        </EasingDoubleKeyFrame>
        //    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        //</Storyboard> 

        var newSB = new Storyboard();
        var da1 = new DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames();
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(da1, new PropertyPath("(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateX)"));
        var da2 = new DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames();
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(da1, new PropertyPath("(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateY)"));

        var ed1 = new EasingDoubleKeyFrame
        {
            KeyTime = KeyTime.FromTimeSpan(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0)), 
            Value = 0
        };

        var ed2 = new EasingDoubleKeyFrame
        {
            KeyTime = KeyTime.FromTimeSpan(timespan),
            Value = x,
            EasingFunction = new CircleEase() {EasingMode = EasingMode.EaseIn}
        };

        var ed3 = new EasingDoubleKeyFrame
        {
            KeyTime = KeyTime.FromTimeSpan(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0)), 
            Value = 0
        };

        var ed4 = new EasingDoubleKeyFrame
        {
            KeyTime = KeyTime.FromTimeSpan(timespan),
            Value = y,
            EasingFunction = new CircleEase() {EasingMode = EasingMode.EaseIn}
        };

        da1.KeyFrames.Add(ed1);
        da1.KeyFrames.Add(ed2);
        da2.KeyFrames.Add(ed3);
        da2.KeyFrames.Add(ed4);
        newSB.Children.Add(da1);
        newSB.Children.Add(da2);

        Storyboard.SetTarget(da1, target); 
        Storyboard.SetTarget(da2, target);

        return newSB;
    }
```

Comment: try to call `SetTargetProperty` after you call `SetTarget`, also try removing the brackets `Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(da1, new PropertyPath("RenderTransform.TranslateX"));`

Comment: In both `SetTargetProperty` uses you have `SetTargetProperty(da1,...` - is that a typo here on OS, or also in actual code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to recode it in following format it works right for me

```
public static Storyboard CreateSimpleTranslation(double x, double y, TimeSpan timespan, FrameworkElement target)
        {
                Storyboard storyboard = new Storyboard();

                DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames da1 = new DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames();
                var ed1 = new EasingDoubleKeyFrame
                {
                    KeyTime = KeyTime.FromTimeSpan(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0)),
                    Value = 0,
                    EasingFunction = new CircleEase() { EasingMode = EasingMode.EaseIn }
                };
                da1.KeyFrames.Add(ed1);

                Storyboard.SetTarget(da1, target);
                Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(da1, new PropertyPath("(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateX)"));

                storyboard.Children.Add(da1); 
                return storyboard;
       }
```